# Kotlin / Regex - Replace a group of pattern with a repeating character

Tags: regex, kotlin

I would like to mask the email passed in the `maskEmail` function. I'm currently facing a problem wherein the **asterisk `*` is not repeating when i'm replacing group 2 and and 4** of my pattern.

Here is my code:

```
fun maskEmail(email: String): String {
    return email.replace(Regex("(\\w)(\\w*)\\.(\\w)(\\w*)(@.*\\..*)$"), "$1*.$3*$5")
}
```

Here is the input:

```
tom.cat@email.com
cutie.pie@email.com
captain.america@email.com
```

Here is the current output of that code:

```
t*.c*@email.com
c*.p*@email.com
c*.a*@email.com
```

**Expected output:**

```
t**.c**@email.com
c****.p**@email.com
c******.a******@email.com
```

Edit:
I know this could be done easily with for loop but **I would need this to be done in regex.** Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if your email contains not just dots and letters? E.g. `my-cutie.pie+here@email.com`? I think you can't rely on just word char checking in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your problem, you need to match each character in the email address that not is the first character in a word and occurs before the `@`. You can do that with a negative lookbehind for a word break and a positive lookahead for the `@` symbol:

```
(?<!\b)\w(?=.*?@)
```

The matched characters can then be replaced with `*`.

Note we use a lazy quantifier (`?`) on the `.*` to improve efficiency.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DEW5Q8/4)

Note also as pointed out by @CarySwoveland, you can replace `(?<!\b)` with `\B` i.e.

```
\B\w(?=.*?@)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DEW5Q8/10)

As pointed out by @Thefourthbird, this can be improved further efficiency wise by replacing the `.*?` with a `[^\r\n@]*` i.e.

```
\B\w(?=[^\r\n@]*@)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FuBB1i/1)

Or, if you're only matching single strings, just `[^@]*`:

```
\B\w(?=[^@]*@)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FuBB1i/2)

Comment: Wonderful! I will set this as the answer, For future reference, this is how we integrate the pattern in kotlin 


fun maskEmail(email: String): String {
    return email.replace(Regex("(?<!\\b)\\w(?=.*@)"), "*")
}


Thank you sir @nick !

Comment: @Mandy8055 no, sorry, you were right, it's not working. I've changed the answer back to lazy. I'm sure I saw it working but it won't any more. A ghost in the machine...

Comment: You could even change the lazy quantifier for a negated character class `\B\w(?=[^\r\n@]*@)`  to prevent some backtracking https://regex101.com/r/FuBB1i/1 +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's interesting how much of a difference that makes. I guess if OP is just comparing a single string they can just skip the `\r\n` part of the class. I'll make a note in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest keeping any char at the start of string and a combination of a dot + any char, and replace any other chars with `*` that are followed with any amount of characters other than `@` before a `@`:

```
((?:\.|^).)?.(?=.*@)
```

Replace with `$1*`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCMvJV/1). This will handle emails that happen to contain chars other than just word (letter/digit/underscore) and `.` chars.

**Details**

- `((?:\.|^).)?` - an optional capturing group matching a dot or start of string position and then any char other than a line break char
- `.` - any char other than a line break char...
- `(?=.*@)` - if followed with any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `@`.

**Kotlin code** (with a *raw string literal* used to define the regex pattern so as not to have to double escape the backslash):

```
fun maskEmail(email: String): String {
    return email.replace(Regex("""((?:\.|^).)?.(?=.*@)"""), "$1*")
}
```

See a [Kotlin test online](https://ideone.com/A44giK):

```
val emails = arrayOf<String>("captain.am-e-r-ica@email.com","my-cutie.pie+here@email.com","tom.cat@email.com","cutie.pie@email.com","captain.america@email.com")
for(email in emails) {    
  val masked = maskEmail(email)
  println("${email}: ${masked}")    
}
```

Output:

```
captain.am-e-r-ica@email.com: c******.a*********@email.com
my-cutie.pie+here@email.com: m*******.p*******@email.com
tom.cat@email.com: t**.c**@email.com
cutie.pie@email.com: c****.p**@email.com
captain.america@email.com: c******.a******@email.com
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still thinking why it is necessary to make this ((?:\.|^).)?   optional? whenever i remove that optional pattern it only display a single asterisk. same with replacing it with (plus)

Comment: @KennethC If the capturing group is not optional, it will require a dot/start-of-string followed with a dot and then any char. You may replace the pattern with its equivalent, `(?:((?:\.|^).)|.)(?=.*@)` if you want (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCMvJV/2)).